# R -- How to conditionally sum binary time series data for large data frames

Tags: r, binary, time-series, cumulative-sum

I've been trying to solve this issue for too long now. I have binary insect outbreak data in annual time series format for 300+ years (rows) and 70+ trees (columns).

I'd like to conditionally fill a dataframe / matrix / data table of the same dimensions with cumulative sums, and have it reset to 0 at the end of each outbreak period. I've found a wealth of similar questions / answers that I just can't seem to translate to my issue.

I'll have a snippet of a dataframe, e.g., that looks like this:

```
      t1 t2 t3 t4 t5
2000   1  0  0  1  0
2001   1  0  0  0  1
2002   1  1  0  0  1
2003   0  1  0  1  1
2004   1  1  1  1  1
```

And I want to create a new df that looks like this:

```
      t1 t2 t3 t4 t5
2000   1  0  0  1  0
2001   2  0  0  0  1
2002   3  1  0  0  2
2003   0  2  0  1  3
2004   1  3  1  2  4
```

I've felt I've gotten close with both the `data.table` and `rle` packages, although I've also been going in tons of circles as well (pretty sure I did it for a single column once, but now can't remember what I did, or why I couldn't get it to work in a loop for all columns...).

I've always gotten the following methods to work to *some* extent, usually just a single column, or add one 1 df on top of a shifted df, so a single column might look like `0 1 2 2 1 0` instead of `0 1 2 3 4 0`. Some attempts, if this helps, have been variations on code looking like this:

```
setDT(dt)[, new := t1 + shift(t1, fill = 0)]


apply(
  rle( matrix)$lengths
  , 2, seq)
rle( matrix[,1])$lengths 


for( i in 1:dim(dt)[1]) {
  for( j in 1:dim(dt)[2]) {
    cols <- names(dt) # tried in place of .SD with negative results
    if( dt[i,j] == 1) {
      dt[, new := .SD + shift(.SD, 1L, fill = 0, type = "lag", give.names = TRUE)]
    } else { dt }
  }
}
```

Some of the main SO sources I've used include these pages: [data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741683/conditional-cumulative-sum-in-r), [dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994060/r-cumulative-sum-by-condition-with-reset), [rle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295833/cumulative-sum-for-positive-numbers-only)

Let me know if I'm missing any important info (I'm new!). & thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rle` with `sequence` from `base R`

```
df2 <- df1 #create a copy of df1
#loop through the columns of 'df2', apply the `rle`, get the 'sequence'
#of 'lengths' and multiply with the column values.
df2[] <- lapply(df2, function(x) sequence(rle(x)$lengths)*x)
df2
#     t1 t2 t3 t4 t5    
#2000  1  0  0  1  0
#2001  2  0  0  0  1
#2002  3  1  0  0  2
#2003  0  2  0  1  3
#2004  1  3  1  2  4
```

Comment: This works quickly and easily. Thanks; a week of tearing my hair out and it's this simple! I never realized I could leave df2's brackets completely empty of references to rows / columns. I've also never toyed with function(x) floating within a function before, defined without {}. That's really new / confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table` combined with the `ave` function to calculate the cumsum of each column grouped by the `rleid` of the column itself:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, names(dt) := lapply(.SD, function(col) ave(col, rleid(col), FUN = cumsum))][]

#   t1 t2 t3 t4 t5
#1:  1  0  0  1  0
#2:  2  0  0  0  1
#3:  3  1  0  0  2
#4:  0  2  0  1  3
#5:  1  3  1  2  4
```